# How tall should I build my minecraft mob farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My first attempt at a mob farm seems to have been too close to the ground. I wasn't getting very many mobs. When I killed mobs at ground level, more mobs would spawn in the mob farm. How tall should I build the next one so that it isn't affected by mobs on ground level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an exp farm your mobs will have to fall 24 blocks to be killable on one hit. That way you get the xp and the special drops.

For mobs to spawn very efficiently you want to be 128 blocks away from any other potential spawning points for them (blocks with block light lower than 8), so you should be 128 blocks above the highest block in an 128 x 128 area around your spawner.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best would be around 24 blocks for the floor. This way you can one hit them and get the exp. you can also add more levels on top of that.

Comment: Not looking for a xp farm, I already have that going with a zombie spawner I found. Trying to find the minimum distance from sea level.

Comment: Okay. Than increase the highly by one or two and have the lowest point where the die as a hopper directed to a chest.

Comment: Sorry I missed some info. For the mod to die it should be 25 blocks I believe. You can make the spawn part larger as well either spawning pads. I think 6x6 is the usual. With half slabs cover the whole pad.

Answer (score 0):

After finding a couple other related discussions it looks like building up 128+ blocks might do the trick.